# Do a subgroup of a Lie group and its connected component have the same Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $G$. We denote by $H^o$ the connected component of $H$. Do $H$ and $H^o$ have the same Lie algebra ?

Comment: Lie algebra *is* the tangent space at the identity. It depends only on the connected component of the identity. And so $H$ and $H^o$ have literally equal Lie algebras.

Comment: @freakish, thank you for your help!